# How to set to my code below charset CODE 737 php-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, iconv

```
public function downloadTXT()
{

    $txt = "";
    $datas = User::select('home_id','home_firstname','home_lastname')
        ->orderBy('home_id','desc')
        ->take(Input::get('number'))
        ->get();

    foreach($datas as $data){
        $txt .= 100000+$data['home_id'].' '.$data['home_firstname'].' '.$data['home_lastname'].PHP_EOL;
    }
    //$txtname = 'mytxt.txt';

    $headers = ['Content-type: text/plain',
                'test'=>'YoYo',
                'Content-Disposition'=>sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', Input::get('name')),
                'X-BooYAH'=>'WorkyWorky',
                //'Content-Length'=>sizeof($datas)
                ];

    return Response::make($txt , 200, $headers );

}
```

How can i iconv the charset which is utf-8 to code 737 that i dont even know the symbol like 'utf-8'

[CODE PAGE 737](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_737) = > LINK

**EDIT**

```
$txt = mb_convert_encoding($txt,'cp737');
```

This doesnt work....does not recognize it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)So i found the solution hope this helps someone.First of all i found the function of PHP and other languages has it "**iconv**" which is well known!

2)Second you must find the coding you need [Net.name of the coding you need for windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

3)Finally here  is the code you need to make the encoding different 
before the return you must convert the txt file

```
$txt = iconv("UTF-8","cp737","$txt");
```

So this means from **utf-8** to **cp737** and the thirst parameter is the txt file we created !